# Relating values in a PHP multiple checkbox array

Tags: php, arrays

I searched and can't find an answer to this and nothing I try works. In this form, for each image (pix) and there the user enters the number of copies to be produced.

I know how to build the array for each individually when the submit button is clicked but I can't get both arrays to relate to each other. I want to produce something like: 01.jpg - 3 copies, 02.jpg - 1 copy etc etc.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

This is my form:

```html
<form action="self.php" method="post">
      <img src="01.jpg" alt="01.jpg">
      <input type="checkbox" name="pix[]" value="01.jpg_album">
      <input type="text" name="quantity[]">

      <img src="02.jpg" alt="02.jpg">
      <input type="checkbox" name="pix[]" value="02.jpg_extra">
      <input type="text" name="quantity[]">

      <img src="03.jpg" alt="03.jpg">
      <input type="checkbox" name="pix[]" value="03.jpg_extra">
      <input type="text" name="quantity[]">

      <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

This is how I extract the values returned:

```html
echo implode('<br>', $_POST['pix']);

echo implode('<br>', $_POST['quantity']);
```

EDITED: FURTHER to my question above and in response to the second code posted by Rajdeep ... I've separated the two processes. The first was to determine whether the client wanted the image for his wedding album, so I did:

```html
        $arr = array("01", "02", "03");

echo "<h3>Images required for album: </h3>";
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
            if(in_array($key, $arr)){
                $var = $value . ".jpg";
                if(isset($_POST[$value]) && !empty($_POST[$value])){
                    echo $var."<br />";
                }//endif
            } //endif
        }// end foreach
```

This output was:

```
03.jpg
04.jpg
23.jpg
etc
```

Then, I wanted to know if he needed any additional individual prints and this code (sort of) worked for that:

```html
echo "<h3>Extras required: </h3>";
$noextras = false;
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
            if(in_array($key, $arr)){
                $var = $value . ".jpg - ";
                    if(isset($_POST[$value . "_extra"]) && !empty($_POST[$value . "_extra"])){
                        $sum = $_POST[$value . '_extra'];
                            if($sum == 1) {
                                $var .= $sum ." copy <br />";
                            } else {
                                $var .= $sum . " copies <br />";
                            }
                echo $var;
                    } else if(empty($_POST[$value . "_extra"])) { $noextras = true; }
            
            } //endif in_array
        
        }// end foreach

if($noextras) { echo "No extra copies needed.";}
```

And the output from this was something like

```
03.jpg - 5 copies
04.jpg - 2 copies
23.jpg - 1 copy
```

I then discovered a snag. This permitted extra copied to be selected for ONLY for images that were selected for inclusion in the album. I have tried various variations on the code and I am coming up with a blank.

So, I've changed this to a two step process. First page, the person selects the images for the album, which when submitted go to a confirmation page to show what had been selected. Once he clicks the 'confirm' button an email goes to me and him.

Clicking the confirm button also goes to a Thank You page which then refreshes into the second page for ordering individual prints. Here he can select how many copies of a print he needs and this works well with Rajdeep's first 'merged' code BUT it only works for one selection.

I've expanded the selection and this is where I am currently having trouble. He has a choice to decides how many copies he needs of each of the four different sizes available (7x6, 9x5, 10x8, 12x8). I am able to process one size only but am having trouble with expanding it to four inputs.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `checkbox` and `text` attribute, why don't you use only one `<input>` with `number` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of two different `<input>` tags with `checkbox` and `text` attribute, use only one `<input>` with `number` attribute for each image. And make the `name` attribute as the name of your image, like this:

```
<form action="self.php" method="post">
    <img src="01.jpg" alt="01.jpg" />
    <input type="number" name="01" min="0" />

    <img src="02.jpg" alt="02.jpg" />
    <input type="number" name="02" min="0" />

    <img src="03.jpg" alt="03.jpg" />
    <input type="number" name="03" min="0" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

And this is how you can process the form,

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        if($key == "submit"){
            continue;
        }
        if(!empty($value)){
            $var = $key . ".jpg - " . $value;
            if($value == 1){
                $var .= " copy";
            }else{
                $var .= " copies";
            }
            $var .= "<br />";
            echo $var;
        }
    }
}
```

A sample output would be like this:

```
01.jpg - 3 copies
02.jpg - 1 copy
03.jpg - 5 copies
```

**Edited:**

Based on your requirement, use `<input type="checkbox" name="xx" value="xx" />` for selecting the image(i.e when user wants this image to be included in photo album) and use `<input type="number" name="xx_extra" min="1" />` for keeping track of how many extra copies of this image user wants.

So your HTML code should be like this:

```
<form action="self.php" method="post">
    <img src="01.jpg" alt="01.jpg" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="01" value="01" />
    <input type="number" name="01_extra" min="1" />

    <img src="02.jpg" alt="02.jpg" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="02" value="02" />
    <input type="number" name="02_extra" min="1" />

    <img src="03.jpg" alt="03.jpg" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="03" value="03" />
    <input type="number" name="03_extra" min="1" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

And this is how you can process the form,

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $arr = array("01", "02", "03");

        foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
            if(in_array($key, $arr)){
                $var = $value . ".jpg - ";
                if(isset($_POST[$value . "_extra"]) && !empty($_POST[$value . "_extra"])){
                    $sum = $_POST[$value . '_extra'] + 1;
                    $var .= $sum . " copies <br />";
                }else{
                    $var .= "1 copy <br />";
                }
                echo $var;
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: That is very nice code! This does work for one of the two parameters I need. I need two bits of info in relation to each image: (1) 'pix' refers to the selection for inclusion into a photo album while (2) 'quantity' refers to whether additional copies are required. You solution works superbly for 'quantity' only ... any idea on including a 'pix' selection?

Comment: @TerryAlly Okay, but clarify this thing first. There is no uniformity in `value` attributes, like one is `xx.jpg_album`, other two are `xx.jpg_extra`. Is it okay if I make all of them uniform like `xx.jpg_album` or `xx.jpg_extra`.

Comment: ah! Yes. Let me explain. For each image that that is displayed, I'm asking my client to select which ones (s)he want for their photo album. So I want a checkbox for that and this was the field I named xx.jpg_album. 2ndly I wanted to provide the option for them to select any extra copies they want to print separately and for this I used xx.jpg_extra. I do like the code you produced which gives me what I need for number of extra copies but I need to add a selection for which images now go into the album.

Comment: @TerryAlly I've updated my answer. Please see the **edited** section of my answer.

Comment: I've tweaked the code and used two foreach statements - one for the image selection for the album and one for the number of extra copies. I don't know how to post the new code again! (How do I do that?) I've run into two difficulties. (1) If I do not click a checkbox I cannot enter extras and (2) I can generate an array for albums but having difficulty generating one for extras. How can I repost my code here?

Comment: @TerryAlly There's an *edit* link below your question, or [you can just click here to edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34788439/edit). Share both of your HTML and PHP code.